# Calculating $\Omega(n)\ge m$ for $n$ in large range

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

It's simple to modify the Sieve of Eratosthenes to calculate $\omega(n)$, the number of distinct prime factors, for a range of $n$, by keeping a counter for each number instead of marking it. I believe that if for every $p$ all the powers of $p$ ($p^2, p^3, \dots$) are counted also, then $\Omega(n)$, the number of prime factors with multiplicity can be calculated.

The Sieve method takes roughly $O(n)$ time and $O(n)$ space for $\omega(n)$. Are there more efficient methods to count the number of $n$ in range $1 \le n \le X$ such that $\Omega(n)=m$ or $\Omega(n)\ge m$, for some $m$? The same applies for $\omega(n)$.

Comment: The sieve of Erathosthenes on the integers $1 \ldots  x$ takes exactly $\sum_{p \le x} \lfloor x/p \rfloor \sim \sum_{n \le x} \frac{1}{\log n} \lfloor x/n \rfloor \sim x \sum_{n \le x} \frac{1}{n\log n} \sim x \log\log x$ operations. When dealing with prime powers it becomes $\sum_{p^k \le x} \lfloor x/p^k \rfloor  \sim x \log \log x$ again. As you see we can't expect much optimization, since evaluating $\Omega(n)$ for $n = 1 \ldots x $ needs at least $\lfloor x \rfloor $ operations.

Comment: @reuns I like to remind myself it's possible to compute $\pi(x)$ without finding all the primes, so perhaps there's a similar approach here.